# Node.js + Mongoose - what's going wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have been studying a node.js + mongoose simple app, however, something went wrong. I have been working based on some examples from this site, but no lucky at all. 
The code runs, however, no records are being returned from db(which is populated, btw). Can someone have a look and gimme some help? I am working on this for more than a day now, but with no joy.

**models/entidade.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   ,Schema = mongoose.Schema
   ,ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var entidadeSchema = new Schema({
        cnpj:  String,
        razaoSocial: String,
        nomeFantasia:   String,
        endereco: String,
        unidades: [{ codigo: String, nome: String, endereco: String, ativo: {type: Boolean, default: true} }],
        dataCriacao: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        cadastroAtivo: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entidade', entidadeSchema);
```

**routes/entidades.js**

```
var Entidade = require('../models/entidade.js');

exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Entidade.find(function(err, entidades) {
        console.log("route IN: %d records", entidades.length );
        res.send(entidades);
    });
};
```

and finally, **server.js**

```
var express = require('express');     
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

// connection to mongoDB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/ccidev');    

var entidade = require('./routes/entidades');

app.get('/entidades/list', entidade.list);

app.listen(3000);
```

As I said, when running the app, I don't get any errors, but an empty result. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Vinicius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), the first argument of Model.find() is the **condition**
Try

```
Entidade.find({}, function(err, entidades) {});
```

**routes/entidades.js**

```
var Entidade = require('../models/entidade.js');

exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Entidade.find({}, function(err, entidades) {
        console.log("route IN: %d records", entidades.length );
        res.send(entidades);
    });
};
```

Comment: At first I thought the same, but `find()` seems to work just fine without any conditions passed (and just a callback). BTW, your answer is missing the conditions as well...

Comment: Yeah guys, the `find()` should just work fine. I have found the issue...the database has been created outside the app. I mean, I did not load the data using the app. So I tried to load the SAME data using a POST method and it worked fine. Data is showing now(the only diff from the previous schema was a `__v` attribute, which has been added by mongoose for version control). Pretty weird, but at least, that's working now! And thanks a lot @lemulot and @robertklep for your thoughts! I really appreciate the feedback! :)